# Validation rules applied to all elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I need to assign validation rules to specific input elements by `id` not `name`.

To do this I'm executing the following code:

```
   $("#cvc").rules("add", { required: true, validateCvc: true });
   $("#cardNumber").rules("add", 
     { creditcard: true, messages: { creditcard: "Invalid Card Number" } });
```

However, this is actually assigning the rules to all inputs on the form. I can verify this by logging the rules attached to a different input:

```
   console.log($("#name").rules());
```

Output:

```
Object {required: true, validateCvc: true, creditcard: true}
```

#### Update

It looks like this may have something to do with the jQuery Validate Unobtrusive plugin which I'm beginning to find is more hassle than it's worth. The code that sets up the validation is calling `validate` before I add the rules:

```
function validationInfo(form) {
    var $form = $(form),
        result = $form.data(data_validation),
        onResetProxy = $.proxy(onReset, form);

    if (!result) {
        result = {
            options: {  // options structure passed to jQuery Validate's validate() method
                errorClass: "input-validation-error",
                errorElement: "span",
                errorPlacement: $.proxy(onError, form),
                invalidHandler: $.proxy(onErrors, form),
                messages: {},
                rules: {},
                success: $.proxy(onSuccess, form)
            },
            attachValidation: function () {
                $form
                    .unbind("reset." + data_validation, onResetProxy)
                    .bind("reset." + data_validation, onResetProxy)
                    .validate(this.options);
            },
            validate: function () {  // a validation function that is called by unobtrusive Ajax
                $form.validate();
                return $form.valid();
            }
        };
        $form.data(data_validation, result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

#### Update 2

Here's a repo - http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/emZB8/

You can see in the console that this is clearly setting up a "required" rule for both fields even though it was not specified on the second.

It would appear if you want to work with validate plugin directly you're better off removing the reference to the unobtrusive plugin.

Comment: Show the rendered HTML of your form and construct a concise demo.  It cannot do what you claim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code as you posted cannot do what you claim.  Provide a concise working demo to show otherwise.

See this demo where the `rule` is only applied to the specified element.

http://jsfiddle.net/tyCvL/

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({  // initialize the plugin
        // options 
    });

    $("#field1").rules("add", { required: true });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1"/>
    <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2"/>
</form>
```

---

**EDIT:**

As per example above, the `name` attribute is not optional.  The jQuery Validate plugin will always require that a `name` attribute be present on all `input` elements for all situations and cases.

**OP's jsFiddle Fixed:  http://jsfiddle.net/emZB8/5/**

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1"/>
    <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2"/>
</form>
```

Comment: In that case this must be an issue relating to the unobstrusive validation plugin.

Comment: @BenFoster, it's impossible to say with what little I can see.

Comment: I've updated my post with the code from the unobstrusive plugin that sets up the validation. This *is* calling `validate` first so the rules *should* only be assigned to the individual elements.

Comment: @BenFoster, regardless, I don't see how targeting one specific `id` can cause the rule to apply to all `id`'s.  I can't make it do this if I wanted.  If anything, I'd expect the `rules('add')` method to just be disabled.

Comment: I've added a repro. Clearly it is an issue with the unobtrusive plugin.

Comment: @BenFoster, that's the weirdest thing I've ever seen.  Don't get me started on an MS rant, but if this were my project, I'd dump `unobtrusive.js` in favor of more custom control.

Comment: @BenFoster, Fixed it.  See my edit.  This is one reason why it's important to show the rendered HTML for the form in one's OP.

Comment: Damn! We can't use names - I was going off [this post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-validate-validating-on-input-id-instead-of-name#14737000002034857) which is why I thought it was possible. Looking through the jQuery.validate source now, any idea why this occurs?

Comment: @BenFoster, the plugin uses the `name` attribute to keep track of everything.  You don't need to reference the `name` from anyplace else, but it must be present in the HTML.  AFAIK, I didn't think leaving the `name` out of an `input` element was even valid HTML.

Comment: @BenFoster, This answer [and that post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-validate-validating-on-input-id-instead-of-name#14737000002034857) is about how to specify rules when you don't **know** the `name`, not for when you leave the `name` out of the HTML.  No matter what, the HTML `input` element needs to have a `name`, even if you don't know it or use it anyplace else.

Comment: Can't see anything that suggests it's not. In any case it looks like not specifying a name will just add a rule for an empty name, hence why all inputs get the rule. Well that's solved that mystery!

Comment: @BenFoster, I can't find it in the docs right now, but there are quite a few SO posts about it.  Definitely, `name` is a required attribute as far as this plugin is concerned.

Answer (score 5):

**jQuery Validate won't work if the inputs don't have unique name attributes.**

I wasted ~2 hours getting this working. Why don't the developers throw and error when I'm not using their plugin correctly?!

Comment: When you set `debug` option to `true`, you will get errors reported to the console.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where validation meant for one field would get applied to all other fields. After setting "debug" to true, jquery validate started throwing "'field' has no name assigned" in the console. I set the name attribute on those problematic fields and voila.. problem solved.

So I guess jquery validate doesn't like unnamed fields.